How to disable this weird FPS counter in Google Chrome?

This weird thing here can be seen in the image above ...

Open your Chrome browser.

Press Ctrl + Shift + I to open Developer Tools.
Press Ctrl + Shift + P to open the Run command.
Type Render and select Hide frames per second (FPS) meter.
The FPS meter will disappear.

or
Type in Chrome browser chrome://flags/#cast-streaming-performance-overlay Select either Default or Disabled.
Check screenshot for details

Developer Tools -> Run Command


Hide Frame per second (fps) meter


Chrome flags - layout




This is a well-written answer, but the indicator in question looks completely different from that in your screenshots.

This appears to be Nvidia's built-in FPS display - or graphics API visual indicator, as they officially call it. It might be enabled either:

via an environment variable __GL_SHOW_GRAPHICS_OSD, which can be set in a variety of places, but Chrome's .desktop file would be the most likely candidate if this indicator doesn't appear in other applications
using Nvidia profiles - open NVIDIA X Server Settings, navigate to the Application Profiles tab, and check if there are any profiles that might match Chrome

